# setting method parameters dynamically from array (working with FindBy method in Doctrine)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Here is my `options array`.

```
array(2) {
 ["status"] => string(1) "1"
 ["dateCreated"] => string(4) "DESC"
}
```

Here is my `hardcoded doctrine findby code`:

```
$posts = Pluto::registry('doctrine')
 ->getRepository(\Application\Entity\Post::class)
 ->findBy(
    ['status'=>1],
    ['dateCreated'=>'DESC']
);
```

What I'm looking for is a **dynamic solution to setting the findBy criteria (N criterias)**.

I got this code somewhere (the 3 dots which i dont actually know what they do so if you could info on that too id appreciate it) and it worked for creating objects but this is how far I've gotten (which doesnt work as it returns.

```
$data = Pluto::registry('doctrine')
   ->getRepository($config->className)
   ->findBy(...array_values($newWhereClauses));

   // or ->findBy(...$newWhereClauses);
```

**As you can see when you pass the parameters into the `findBy` method you are not actually passing an array but a list of columns and criterias**

How can I convert the findBy parameters to be dynamically from the `original options array`

Comment: The three dots is a [Variable-length argument list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and was introduced in PHP 5.6. It's basically a new, shorter (and clearer) syntax for `func_get_args()`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok is this the correct path though? How do i dynamically add the options array into the findBy method

Comment: You can't use that when you call the function,  only in the function defintion like: `public function myFunction(...$hello)`.  Then all arguments (no matter how many) you pass to the function will be added to the `$hello` variable as an array.

Comment: ok well how do i get to pass each part of the options array as a parameter into the findBy method

Comment: Added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send several (dynamic amount) of parameters to a method, you can use the `call_user_func_array()` like this:

```
$arguments = [
    ['status'=>1],
    ['dateCreated'=>'DESC']
];

$queryInstance = Pluto::registry('doctrine')
     ->getRepository(\Application\Entity\Post::class);

$posts = call_user_func_array(
    [$queryInstance, 'findBy'], 
    $arguments
);
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php